# I have code compiled for Intel i7: how can I know which Xeon processors it could run on?

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel, xeon

I have code compiled for Intel i7: how can I know which Xeon processors it could run on?

There seems to be no clear way to know.

I developed these rules-of-thumb, but am unsure if they suffice. The Xeon processors that could run i7 code should be:

- Of or after the [Nehalem_(microarchitecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_(microarchitecture)) family of processors.
- Support DDR-4 memory.
- Of lithography process of 45nm or smaller.
- From the year 2008 onwards.

Is there a table somewhere on the web that makes comparisons between Core and Xeon processors in terms of which code they could run?

---

Edit1:
The [compiler switch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) is `gcc --march=corei7`

Comment: What does it mean that it was compiled for "i7"? That doesn't make much sense. i7 is a marketing term, not a processor family or architecture.

Comment: When the code was compiled, one of the compiling arguments was _i7_.

Comment: Eh? What compiler had that as an argument?!

Comment: @Michael: `gcc --march=corei7` (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html)

Comment: Hm, I suspect they really mean Nehalem given the description, but it's bizarre that they would actually put `corei7` as the actual command line parameter. Indeed, in later versions of gcc it has been renamed to `nehalem`.

Answer (score 3):

To get an idea on what processsor the binary can run it is important to look up the cpu flags. In this case:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html

```
nehalem

Intel Nehalem CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and POPCNT instruction set support.
```

These do relate to the cpu hardware features, which can be found in `/proc/cpuinfo` on a Linux based system. If all of the above (and more) features are listed, then it should be possible to run the binary. 
The `--march` selector just summarizes several cpuflags into a single argument.

In case more detailed information on that topic is needed, I can recommed the Gentoo C(XX)FLAGS documentation.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization#-march

If there is no access to `/proc/cpuinfo` available, these informations can be found as well in the hardware specifications (datasheet) of the processor. The names of the features in the specifications typically correspond to the gcc cpu flags.